# What visual object should I use for a lot of for nonmoving objects in Unity?

Tags: unity, architecture

The objects only need to mouse clicked but there are 1000 of them. They don't move- they have color modulation and text. I was thinking buttons, can Unity reliably handle so many of them? Or do I need Sprites or some other visual object? For starters it is a web game but later Android.

Comment: Why not just try it out and see how many FPS you get when you build and run it on your target platform?

Comment: I tried with GODOT- Sprite mouse reactivity was poor. Buttons are too bloated. TextRect are non-responsive altogether.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that you will have the same problems with Unity.

Comment: I also want to know which type to focus on learning